# NSMutableDictionary returning (null) for valid key/forget its values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, null, nsmutabledictionary

Ok. I have a class "Game", which creates an instance of my class "Board", and tests it.

The "Board" class has a dictionary, which seems to somehow not being able to keep it's values(?)
Tried to strap down the code to the minimal:

The Game class:

```c
@interface Game : UIViewController{
    Board *board;
}
-(void)testAgain; 

@implementation Game
-(void)setup{
    board = [Board alloc]createBoard];
    [board test]; //returns right value
    [self testAgain]; //returns (null), see output below
}
-(void)testAgain{
    [board test];
}

-(void)didLoad{
    [self setup];
}
```

The Board Class:

```c
@interface Board : NSObject{
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dict;

-(Board *)createBoard;
-(void)test;

@implementation Board
@synthesize dict;

-(Board *)createBoard{

    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setObject:@"foo1" forKey:@"1"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo2" forKey:@"2"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo3" forKey:@"3"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo4" forKey:@"4"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo5" forKey:@"5"];

    return self;
}

-(void)test{
    NSLog(@"Test return: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"4"]);
}
```

The following output:

```
2012-06-23 01:05:28.614 Game[21430:207] Test return: foo4
2012-06-23 01:05:32.539 Game[21430:207] Test return: (null)
```

In advance, thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this an ARC project? Also, can you verify that any line above which has `dict` on it is not modified from your code (spare no details for those lines)?

Comment: I did meet the same issue before, I also want to know why? I solved it by adding property to the variable.

Comment: This is an ARC project, dict is not modified anywhere else. But I found the error, I had managed to add a second board = [Board alloc]init] inside my huge -(void)setup, which deleted the whole dictionary. So it was entirely a dumb error created by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@implementation Game
-(void)setup{
    board = [[[Board alloc] init] createBoard];
    [board test]; //returns right value
    [self testAgain]; //returns (null), see output below
}
```

The creation pattern you are using is outside every convention in Objective-C. You should either use [Board new], [[Board alloc] init|With...|] or [Board board|With...|].

```
-(Board *)createBoard {

    self.dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setObject:@"foo1" forKey:@"1"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo2" forKey:@"2"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo3" forKey:@"3"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo4" forKey:@"4"];
    [dict setObject:@"foo5" forKey:@"5"];
}
```

Lets see if your code works better with the missing init reinstalled where it belongs and that little missing self. .

Comment: My -(void)setup{} function is really long, and after reading it many, many times and NSLogging the whole thing through, I found out that I had "[[Board alloc] init]" hidden inside it a second time, without the "createBoard". 

Removing this solved everything, so I have noone else to blame but myself!


But thanks for the heads-up on how to correctly initialize the Board!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not correctly initializing the `Board` object using `createBoard`. You are not even returning a `Board` object in that method. Try modifying that method to something like this:

```
-(id)initWithCreatedBoard {

self = [super init];


if (self) { 

dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:@"foo1" forKey:@"1"];
[dict setObject:@"foo2" forKey:@"2"];
[dict setObject:@"foo3" forKey:@"3"];
[dict setObject:@"foo4" forKey:@"4"];
[dict setObject:@"foo5" forKey:@"5"];

[dict retain];

}
```

return self;

}

You also might want to `retain dict`. Because they are probably getting deallocated.

Also, are you using ARC?

Another thing, instead of having two method `testAgain` and `test`. Just call `test` twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

[self test];

}
```

Just better structure, thats it. Please feedback your results!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the heads-up on how to initialize correctly. I'm using ARC, and did have "return self" in the function, but it disappeared in  all the copying/pasting :) Found the error though, can only blame myself, I had an extra board = [Board alloc]init] hidden in my quite huge -(void)setup file